# When is a type not a type? Error: 'is a type, which is not valid in the given context'

Tags: c#, types, typeof

Consider the following code, the first call to `AcceptType1` compiles fine, however the second call of `AcceptType1(XYZ);` fails. The specific error is:

> Error CS0119  'XYZ' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

I'm not understanding the the specifics behind the error message, and from that I'm failing to understand why the second call fails if `XYZ` is a type which is exactly what `AcceptType1` accepts. If `XYZ` is a type, then why the need to then call `typeof`?

```
public class XYZ
{
}

public class Tester
{

    public void RunTest()
    {
        AcceptType1(typeof(XYZ));
        AcceptType1(XYZ);
    }

    private void AcceptType1(Type t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: XYZ is symbol and typeof(XYZ) is type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`XYZ` is a symbol or name to the class `XYZ`. `typeof` will get the runtime information about the type, which is `System.Type`. You can also pass type symbols with generics, which doesn't work with `typeof`:

```
AcceptType1<T>()
```

where `T` can be filled in with a type symbol or name.

Answer (score 1):

`XYZ` may be a type, but it's not a `Type`, which is what your method expects as a parameter. `typeof(XYZ)` gives you the `Type` for the class `XYZ`.